# Are Neo4j DBs stored in the same way on Windows vs Mac?

Tags: neo4j

I would like to know if a neo4j db created on a Mac will work if the db directory was copied to, and run from, a Windows PC.

NB The neo4j versions would be consistent (1.9 or 2.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the store files are the same.

Updated, because apparently some people thought that wasn't clear enough: You can zip up the files, copy them from your mac to your windows machine, and open them in Neo4j without problems. The store files are stored in the same format on all versions of Neo4j. (By versions I mean all architectures, the different versions--1.9, 2.0, etc., do store things differently)